# libIEC61850 Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.UnresolvedBuildDependencyProjectReference" reference could not be resolved?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Hello i im running Visual studio 2022 professional. I have downloaded libiec61850-1.5.1 [libIEC61850](https://libiec61850.com/downloads/) I have compiled the code whit cmake. I have then opened it in visual studio code. The problem is that the References in the example projects could not be resolved.

I have tried the following things.

1. Remove the references then add them again save and rebuild project.
2. Remove the references the save rebuild project, closed and started visual studio again
   the tried add the references.
3. Tried edit the path directly in vcxproj file.
4. I downloaded the libIEC61850 a second time to make sure there was no corrupt files. Made
   a new compile whit cmake. still got the same problem,
5. Updated the visual studio to the newest update.

Anybody that have a idea what the problem can be. I have searched the a found nothing that could help. i have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900789/how-to-solve-the-microsoft-visualstudio-projectsystem-references-unresolvedbui) also
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Link to library dependencies was not set to "True".
After i changed this the reference error did go away.